# Rails ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, mail-form

rails 6.0.3

I have set up a static mail form using the `gem 'mail_form'`.

I know that it working correctly because I can send an email from the rails console.

The issue is on the form, when I press submit, it is coming up with a routing error.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/"):
```

**home page form**

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_with model: @contact do |f| %>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <h3><%= f.label :name, class: "label" %></h3>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write name in here" %>
      <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write email in here" %>
      <%= f.text_field :message, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write message in here" %>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :contact, only: [:create]
```

**contact.rb**

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name, validate: true
  attribute :email, validate: true
  attribute :message
  def headers
    {
      subject: "My Contact Form",
      to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
      from: %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

**contact_controller.rb**

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new()
    @contact.name = params[:name]
    @contact.email = params[:email]
    @contact.message = params[:message]
    if @contact.deliver

      render json: {message: "Email sent successfully"}
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render json: @contact.errors
    end
  end
end
```

What have I done wrong or what step have I missed?

**edited controller**

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.deliver
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render json: @contact.errors
    end
  end

  private
  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :message)
  end
end
```

**edited form**

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_for Contact.new, url: contacts_path do |f| %>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <h3><%= f.label :name, class: "label" %></h3>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write name in here" %>
      <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write email in here" %>
      <%= f.text_field :message, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write message in here" %>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**edited routes.rb**

```
resources :contacts, only: [:create]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resources :contacts, only: [:create]
```

Resources should be plural.

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.deliver
      # You can't both render and redirect 
      render json: { message: "Email sent successfully" }
    else
      render json: @contact.errors
    end
  end

  private
  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact)
          .permit(:name, :email, :message)
  end
end
```

The parameters are nested in `params[:contact][:name]`, `params[:contact][:email]` etc. Use [strong parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) to whitelist the parameters for mass assignment instead of acting as a human compiler.

Comment: Seems like the form is trying to post to root "/" which would suggest `@contact` is not set in the action that loads the home page

Comment: Thank you. I changed the controller to include strong params and when I got the post to work, I realised I couldn't re_direct too. Thanks for the note on resources being plural too, it makes a lot of sense and well explained

Answer (score 1):

@form cannot automatically resolve a path, I think:

```
 <%= form_with model: @contact do |f| %>
```

- Try adding an explicit url: `form_with model: @contact, url: contacts_path`
- Also make sure to make **controllers always plural** like @max said, if using `resource` or `resources`, otherwise sooner or later Rails gets confused from my experience. On the other hand, your contact only has one method, you can just add a manual route for that and don't rely on Rails auto naming magic:

```rb
# routes

  post "/contact"

# this should also generate a `contact_path` helper, which you can use in the
```

Comment: `form_with` likely cannot infer the path because `@contact` is `nil`. In this case `model` is unnecessary (keyword `model:` defaults to `nil`) and `url` alone would be sufficient.

Comment: @engineersmnky good point! Author can also set the @contact variable, or just pass ``form_for Contact.new, url: contact_path``.

Comment: thanks @engineersmnky and @stwienert, I have edited the code in my question to reflect the changes you wrote. i've learnt a lot about ```form_for``` and ```form_with``` today, it's great to have a network of people that have the knowledge to share

Comment: This advice here is questionable at best, just fix the underlying issues instead.